# How do utilize the fullscreen in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, fullscreen

Does anyone know how to make your website fill the entire screen in ActionScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean full browser flash, there is an [article on devnet](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/liquid_gui.html), among many other [online resources](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=full+browser+flash+as3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

If you mean fullscreen mode, here's another [devnet article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html) on that.

You've got code, files and explanations there.

Goodluck.